# Wro-maven plugin - CSS changes are overwritten

Tags: maven-plugin, wro4j

Using `Wro-maven plugin` version `1.8.0`. When a CSS file is updated, once clean install is triggered on Maven, the changes are lost in CSS file and old file is present.

```html
           <plugin>
                <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                 <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                    <minimize>true</minimize>
                    <destinationFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/wro/</destinationFolder>
                    <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</contextFolder>
                    <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wro.xml</wroFile>
                    <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
                    <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
                    <ignoreMissingResources>false</ignoreMissingResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

please help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, My Bad.

We were editing a file which was generated as a part of wro-maven plugin.

Wro.xml holds list of groups. Each group will be generated as a file (either css/js).  Each group holds a list of files clubbed together, configurable in wro.xml

We were actually editing the file which was a group generated as minimized version and hence changes are overwritten during each clean install. Editing the source file was the correct way.

Found the reason at last.

Thanks.